# I want to add popup confirmation message when i delete in php. how?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want this option when i press delete button then show confirmation message on popup. And if i press yes button then it delete otherwise no.

Comment: Add your html and js here.

Comment: have you tried to search on internet for this ?

Comment: you want to add jquery popup or browser confirmation box?

Answer (score 2):

Follow this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2yEtK/3/) for jquery delete confirmation message.

## HTML

```
<a class="removeRecord" href="#">Delete</a>
```

## JS

```
$("a.removeRecord").live("click",function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
   if(confirm("Do you want to delete?")) {
    this.click;
       alert("Ok");
   }
   else
   {
       alert("Cancel");
   }       
   event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: `.live` has been deprecated (http://api.jquery.com/live/) since jquery1.7 and has been removed from jquery1.9. Better to use `.on`. Downvoted.

Comment: Yeah you are right :)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<td><a onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Please confirm deletion');\" href='delete.php?id=".$query2['id']."'>x</a></td><tr>"; //use double quotes for js inside php!
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#btnDelete').click(function(){
   //Clicking on Yes returns true, No returns false;
   return confirm('Do you want to Delete ?');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/). It's jquery plugin for popup. For delete popup, SweetAlert provides the following snippet.

```
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
  closeOnConfirm: false
},
function(){
  swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
});
```

Follow the [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) documentation for the integration to your project.
Let us know if you have any difficulty in integrating it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in single line code;

```
<a onclick="return confirm('Sure?');" href="http://example.com/delete">Delete</a>
```